# No template found for LeadsController#create, rendering head :no_content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model, controller, dropbox

So I'm trying to send a contact us form into dropbox, so the goal is for a user to create a lead (contact us form) with an upload_file field (attachment) and then I'm going to ask that user if he wants to become a customer irl, so if he becomes one, I want that attachment in his lead (contact us form related to him) to go into my dropbox.

so here is my contact us controller:

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
    require 'dropbox_api'
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    def create
        @lead = Lead.new

        fullname = params['Name']
        company = params['Company']
        email = params['Email']
        phone = params['Phone']
        projectName = params['ProjectName']
        projectDescription = params['ProjectDescription']
        department_incharge = params['DepartmentInCharge']
        message = params['Message']
        attachment = params['attachment']


        @lead.full_name = fullname
        @lead.company_name = company
        @lead.email = email
        @lead.phone = phone
        @lead.project_name = projectName
        @lead.project_description = projectDescription
        @lead.department_in_charge = department_incharge
        @lead.message = message
        params_attach = attachment

        if params_attach
            @lead.attachment = params_attach.read
            @lead.original_filename = params_attach.original_filename


        client = DropboxApi::Client.new(ENV['DROPBOX_OAUTH_BEARER'])

        @lead.save!
        redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
 end
```

here is my customer model:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lead
    has_many :buildings
    belongs_to :address
    belongs_to :user

    after_update :dropbox

   self.all.each do |lead|
    def dropbox
       self.lead.all.each do |lead|
         if lead.attachment != nil
           client = DropboxApi::Client.new(ENV['DROPBOX_OAUTH_BEARER'])
           client.create_folder("/#{lead.full_name}")
           client.upload("/#{lead.full_name}/#{File.basename(lead.original_filename)}", lead.attachment)
             # lead.file_attachment = nil
             # lead.original_filename = nil
             # lead.save!
             end
           end
       end
   end
end
```

The problem is when i hit the send button to confirm my quote, it just refreshes the page (it's supposed to go to a confirmation page) and in the ubuntu console, this appears:

No template found for LeadsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 795ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Tell me if you need any more information, I'm really stuck on that one

Comment: What if you don't have params_attach? you should have else block attached to if block. This might be the case of missing param_attach

Comment: This worked THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, move `redirect_to` out of `if`, add flash message to make it more clear, I suspect `params_attach` is `false`/`nil` in this case

```
if params_attach
   @lead.attachment = params_attach.read
   @lead.original_filename = params_attach.original_filename


   client = DropboxApi::Client.new(ENV['DROPBOX_OAUTH_BEARER'])

   @lead.save!

end
redirect_to root_path
```

Hope that helps!